# Como editar uma li com Javascript?

Tags: javascript

**Objectivo:** Pegar o conteúdo do `<li>`, jogar no campo texto, alterar, devolver pressionando <kbd>Enter</kbd> e limpar o campo.

**Resultado:** O mais próximo que consigo é pegar o conteúdo, editar no campo texto, devolver na lista mas não consigo limpar o campo sem que de algum problema em um elemento do `<li>`.

**Pergunta:** É possível fazer isso utilizando esse código?

Meu código atual:

```js
let lista = document.querySelector('.lista');
let campo = document.querySelector('.campo');

lista.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    let y = event.target;
    campo.value = y.textContent;
    campo.addEventListener('keypress',function(event){
        if(event.keyCode === 13) {
            y.textContent = event.target.value;
            y = '';
        };
    });
});
```

```html
 <ul class="lista">
    <li class="lista__item">um</li>
    <li class="lista__item">dois</li>
    <li class="lista__item">tres</li>
 </ul>
<input class="campo" type="text" name="" id="">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um primeiro problema é que você está adicionando o evento `click` à lista toda:

```
let lista = document.querySelector('.lista');
```

Se você clicar fora de uma `LI` mas dentro da `UL`, irá disparar o evento e o resultado será que o campo irá receber o texto de todas as `LI`.

Para resolver isso você pode verificar se o elemento que disparou o evento (`event.target`) é uma `LI` (e não a `UL`).

Isso foi uma coisa, agora a outro problema é que ao aninhar um evento dentro do outro, cada vez que o evento principal for disparado, irá criar na memória uma instância do evento aninhado. Trocando em miúdos, cada vez que você clicar numa `LI`, irá criar um escutador de evento `keypress` no campo, e isso fará com que cada vez que tecla enter for pressionada, irá disparar o evento `onkeypress` várias vezes, no mesmo número de vezes que o evento click foi disparado.

O que você pode fazer é separar os eventos e declarar uma variável, fora dos dois eventos, para armazenar a `LI` que está sendo editada:

```js
// aguarda o carregamento do DOM
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   let lista = document.querySelector('.lista');
   let campo = document.querySelector('.campo');
   let li; // variável que receberá a LI que está sendo editada
   
   lista.addEventListener('click',function(event){
       li = event.target;
       if(li.tagName == "LI"){ // verifica se é uma LI
          campo.value = li.textContent;
       }
   });
   
   campo.addEventListener('keypress',function(event){
     if(event.keyCode === 13 && li) {
         li.textContent = campo.value;
         campo.value = ''; // esvazia o campo
         li = null; // reseto a variável
     };
   });
});
```

```html
<ul class="lista">
    <li class="lista__item">um</li>
    <li class="lista__item">dois</li>
    <li class="lista__item">tres</li>
 </ul>
<input class="campo" type="text" name="" id="">
```

Comment: Fala, Sam! Acabei de rodar seu código e debugga-lo. Aconteceu o mesmo erro do outro, se você selecionar a Li e clicar enter ele repassa o valor, porém se eu clicar enter novamente, sem ter mudado o target clicando em outra li, então ele passa o campo em branco para a li, alterando novamente. Para isso, seguiu o mesmo princípio do outro código, adicionei li = '' no final do evento campo.addEventListener('keypress',function(event) e rodou perfeitamente. De qualquer forma, ambas as propostas me ajudaram bastante, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Eu alterei o código agora há pouco antes do seu comentário.

Comment: Putz, perfeito!!! Muito obrigado por ter disposto um pouco do seu tempo em ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

O problema é que você não consegue limpar o `input` após pressionar enter?

Bom, o problema é que você está colocando `y = ''`, sendo que `y` é o `target` de `event` de sua lista.

Para você limpar o conteúdo do `input`, basta você colocar `event.target.value = ''` dentro de sua condição, ficando assim:

```
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   y.textContent = event.target.value;
   event.target.value = "";
}
```

Percebi também que ele adiciona um novo evento toda vez que executa o `click`, causando erros imprevistos, então tomei a liberdade para arrumar isso.

```
lista.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    let y = event.target;
    campo.value = y.textContent;
    campo.onkeypress = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            y.textContent = event.target.value;
            event.target.value = "";
        }
    };
});
```

Apenas troquei `addEventListener` por `onkeypress =`

Comment: Perfeito, Lucas! Sua substituição de addEventListener para onkeypress foi a solução! Rodei no Debugger do navegador e para ficar perfeito, só foi preciso manter o y='''; Assim, ele zera o target armazenado na variável e caso eu pressione enter sem ter clicado novamente em alguma Li, ele não repasse o valor do campo (seja qual for) para o target que havia sido selecionado. Muitíssimo obrado!!!